# Converting LaTeX tables into R dataframes/matrices

Tags: r, latex

The process of converting R outputs into LaTeX is well documented. However, the opposite not so much.
**The problem:** I  have a long LaTeX file and would like to import the tables it into R (say, convert them as data frames).

**Question:** is there an elegant/efficient way of doing this task without having to do it manually?

Note that there are percent signs (%) commenting the rows in the tables.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{natbib}

\title{Processing \LaTeX{} tables with R}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
Here is the first table

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Some data}
\begin{tabular}{l|l|}
c1 & c2\\\hline
a & b \\% comments   
c & \cite{mypaper} \\% # more comments 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

and the second:

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{More data}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2   \\% mycomment:"first row"
3 & 4   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Desired output in R:**

```
## Table 1
c1 c2
a  b
c  cite{mypaper}

## Table 2
1    2
3    4
```

Comment: This appears to me answered in the tex stackexchange: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341899/latex-to-markdown-converter

Comment: Extract the tablular content to another file and then try: `read.table('abc.txt',sep = '&',comment.char = '\\')`