# Can I put a latex table into an r data frame?

Tags: r

Someone else built a table using latex formatting into the r markdown file I am using. I want to be able to put the data contained in the table directly into an r data frame that I can then manipulate using r code. The table was not uploaded in a .tex file--it just looks like this in code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|cccc|c}
\hline 
  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Number of Siblings}} & \\
  \textbf{Time Zone} & \textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4+} & \textbf{Total}\\ 
\hline
  \textbf{Eastern} & 3 & 6 & 1 & 14 & 24\\
  \textbf{Central} & 4 & 12 & 5 & 20 & 41\\
  \textbf{Mountain} & 21 & 6 & 3 & 7 & 37 \\
  \textbf{Pacific} & 6 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 25\\
\hline
  \textbf{Total} & 34 & 26 & 16 & 50 & 126\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
 \end{table}
```

I want to put this into an r data frame to graph it, for example. Any help in doing this would be appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Comment: You'll need to provide an example of what you want it to look like. You'll likely need to parse out the values: I.e. take all of that as text (you can put it in quotes" then use regular expression with grep() to pull out the values you want.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Same as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49375555/converting-latex-tables-into-r-dataframes-matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that myfile.tex has the lines shown in the question and no other lines that begin with `\textbf` (possibly preceded by space), first read it into `L`, extract the lines that begin with `\textbf{` (possibly preceded by space) giving `L2` and then remove the `\textbf{...}` leaving only the enclosed part to give `L3`.  Now read that in using `read.table` giving `DF`.

```
L <- readLines("myfile.tex")
L2 <- grep("^ *.textbf", L, value = TRUE)
L3 <- gsub(".textbf.(.*?)\\}", "\\1", L2)
DF <- read.table(text = L3, sep = "&", header = TRUE, 
  strip.white = TRUE, check.names = FALSE, comment.char = "\\")
```

giving:

```
> DF
  Time Zone  1  2  3 4+ Total
1   Eastern  3  6  1 14    24
2   Central  4 12  5 20    41
3  Mountain 21  6  3  7    37
4   Pacific  6  2  8  9    25
5     Total 34 26 16 50   126
```