# Plotting coefficients in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, visualization

I have this LaTex table formatted from an output of OxMetrics:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L*{7}{c} @{}} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent variables} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){2-7} 
& {(1)} & {(2)} & {(3)} & {(4)} & {(5)} & {(6)} \\ 
    
\midrule
Disabilities &-8.016{$^{***}$} &9.221{$^{***}$} &5.625{$^{**}$} &-2.589 &0.739 &4.281\\ 
&(2.121) & (3.090) & (2.588) &(3.105) & (3.917) & (2.730)\\
Disabled x Unemployed
&5.068\\
&(3.224)\\
\midrule
Visual
&-7.146{$^{**}$}&-2.684&10.615{$^{**}$}&4.429&13.730{$^{*}$}&0.270\\
&(3.316)&(5.870)&(4.689)&(5.907)&(7.514)&(5.250)\\
Hearing
&-6.515&8.604&12.039{$^{**}$}&7.222&7.964&1.007\\
&(3.735)&(6.628)&(5.877)&(6.878)&(8.704)&(5.969)\\
Motor   
&-11.283{$^{***}$}&7.511{$^{*}$}&7.856&2.546&5.034&-2.770\\
&(2.544)&(5.168)&(4.455)&(5.443)&(6.434)&(4.499)\\
Episodic
&-0.183&5.794&1.384&2.780&7.353&2.667\\
&(2.391)&(4.516)&(3.751)&(4.578)&(5.718)&(3.981)\\
\midrule 
L   
&-4868& -2251& -1954& -2227& -2411& -2361\\
N
&1159&  640&    624&    628&    645&    639\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\caption*{\tiny{{***}$p<0.01$. 
  {**}$p<0.05$. 
  {*}$p<0.1$. Standard errors in parentheses -- Intercept and other socio-demographic variables (age, sex, marital status, etc.) included but not reported}}

\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

I want to plot these coefficients but I have no clue how to proceed. If the model was estimated with R, it'd be easier. But it's done with another software (OxMetrics). Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Can you export these values from OxMetrics as a CSV file, Excel file or any other standard format that can be read by R? That would probably be the simplest solution. Otherwise, you could always read the latex code as a string and write R code to clean it - but it would be time consuming and error prone.

Comment: If you only have a .tex file, you can read it in as readlines and then use a series of regular expressions to clean it up and eventually create a d.f. See here for one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60243969/can-i-put-a-latex-table-into-an-r-data-frame